# SQL Server: How to achieve re-usability yet flexibility in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`. I am having some problems finding an effective coding pattern  for `SQL` which supports **code re-usability** as well as **flexibility**. By re-usability, what I mean is keeping `SQL` queries in `Stored Procedures` and `User Defined Functions`.

Now, if I choose `Stored Procedures`, I will be sacrificing its usability in a query directly. If I choose `User Defined Functions`, I won't be able to use `DML` statements.

For example, suppose I created a `Stored Procedures` which inserts one **contact** record. Now, if I am having a table which can act as a source of multiple **contact** records, all I am left with are either `WHILE` loops or `CURSOR`s, which is clearly not a recommended option, due to its performance drawbacks. And due to the fact that DML statements are not allowed in `User Defined Functions`, I simply cannot use them for this purpose.

Although, If I am not concerned with **code re-usability**, then instead of using `Stored Procedures` I can surely use same set of queries again and again to avoid while loops.

What pattern should I follow?

Here is a similar `Stored Procedures`:-

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[InsertTranslationForCategory]                           
(                          
 @str nvarchar(max),                          
 @EventId   int,                         
 @CategoryName NVarchar(500),                        
 @LanguageId int,                       
 @DBCmdResponseCode Int Output,                    
 @KeyIds nvarchar(max)  Output                     
)as                          
BEGIN                    

DECLARE @XmlData XML                           
DECLARE @SystemCategoryId Int                      
DECLARE @CategoryId Int                      
Declare @Counter int=1                      
Declare @tempCount Int                      
Declare @IsExists int                      
Declare @TranslationToUpdate NVarchar(500)                     
Declare @EventName Varchar(200)                       
declare @Locale nvarchar(10)                    
declare @Code nvarchar(50)                    

declare @KeyName nvarchar(200)                    
declare @KeyValue nvarchar(500)                    

select @Locale=locale from languages where languageid =  @LanguageId                    

  SET @DBCmdResponseCode = 0                     
  SET @KeyIds = ''                    
  select   @EventName = eventName from eventLanguages                    
  where eventID = @EventId                    
--BEGIN TRY                         

   Select @SystemCategoryId=CategoryId from SystemCategories  where Name=rtrim(ltrim(@CategoryName))                      
   Select @CategoryId=CategoryId from Categories  where Name=rtrim(ltrim(@CategoryName)) and EventId=@EventId                      
   if (@str='deactivate')              
  Begin              
  Delete from Codetranslation where CategoryId=@CategoryId               
  Update Categories set [Status]=0, Isfilter=0 where  CategoryId=@CategoryId  and Eventid=@EventId              
    Set @DBCmdResponseCode=2              
  return              
  End                 
   set @XmlData=cast(@str as xml)                      
 DECLARE @temp TABLE                      
 (                      
   Id int IDENTITY(1,1),                      
   Code varchar(100),                      
   Translation varchar(500),                      
   CategoryId  int                       
 )                      



 Insert into @temp (Code,Translation,CategoryId)                      
 SELECT                         
    tab.col.value('@Code', 'varchar(200)'),                                            
    tab.col.value('@Translation', 'varchar(500)'),@SystemCategoryId                              
    FROM   @XmlData.nodes('/Data') AS tab (col)                       



  select @tempCount=Count(*) from @temp                      

  if(IsNull(@CategoryId,0)>0)                      
  Begin                        

    While (@Counter <= @tempCount)                      
    Begin                       

       Select @IsExists= count(sc.categoryid) from @temp t Inner Join SystemCodetranslation sc                      
       On sc.categoryid=t.CategoryId                      
       where ltrim(rtrim(sc.code))=ltrim(rtrim(t.code)) and  ltrim(rtrim(sc.ShortTranslation))=ltrim(rtrim(t.Translation))                      
      and t.Id= @Counter                      
         print @IsExists              
         Select @Code = Code , @KeyValue = Translation from @temp where id=@counter                        


      set @KeyName =   ltrim(rtrim(@EventName)) + '_' + ltrim(rtrim(@CategoryName))  + '_' +   ltrim(rtrim(@Code)) + '_LT'                    
      exec dbo.AddUpdateKeyValue  @EventId,@Locale, @KeyName,@KeyValue,NULL,12                    

      select  @KeyIds = @KeyIds +  convert(varchar(50),keyvalueId) + ',' from dbo.KeyValues                    
      where eventid = @EventId and keyname = @KeyName and locale =  @Locale                    


      set @KeyName = ''                    
      set @KeyValue = ''                    

     Set @Counter= @Counter + 1                      

     Set @IsExists=0                      

    End                      

  End                       




  --- Inser data in Codetranslation table                      
  if(isnull(@CategoryId,0)>0)                      
  Begin                      
  print @CategoryId                      
  Delete from codetranslation where categoryid=@CategoryId                     
  Insert into codetranslation (CategoryId,Code,LanguageId,ShortTranslation,LongTranslation,SortOrder)                      
   SELECT                         
    @CategoryId,                      
    tab.col.value('@Code', 'varchar(200)'), @LanguageId,                                           
    tab.col.value('@Translation', 'varchar(500)'),                       
    tab.col.value('@Translation', 'varchar(500)'),0                             
    FROM   @XmlData.nodes('/Data') AS tab (col)                  
    Update Categories set [Status]=1 where  CategoryId=@CategoryId  and Eventid=@EventId                

  End                      
  Set @DBCmdResponseCode=1                      
set @KeyIds =  left(@KeyIds,len(@KeyIds)-1)                                            


END
```

Comment: can you post some code like what are the re-usable queries that you are concerned for along with their input and return types..

Comment: please show some example (pseudo) code and structure

Comment: Can you add some information on what the SP Vcopious_SAP_Core_Translations_Prod_Events_GCO.dbo.AddUpdateKeyValue is doing? If i got you right replacing this one is at the core of your question.

Comment: I don't know internals of `AddUpdateKeyValue` as it is created by some other developer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use table variable parameter for your user defined functions.

following code is an example of using table variable parameter in stored procedure.

```
CREATE TYPE IdList AS TABLE (Id INT)

CREATE PROCEDURE test 
    @Ids dbo.IdList READONLY
AS
   Select *
   From YourTable
   Where YourTable.Id in (Select Id From @Ids)
End
GO
```

In order to execute your stored procedure use following format:

```
Declare @Ids dbo.IdList
Insert into @Ids(Id) values(1),(2),(3)

Execute dbo.test @Ids
```

**Edit**

In order to return Inserted Id, I don't use from Table Variable Parameter. I use following query sample for this purpose.

```
--CREATE TYPE NameList AS TABLE (Name NVarChar(100))

CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @Names dbo.NameList READONLY
AS
   Declare @T Table(Id Int)

   Insert Into YourTable (Name)
   OUTPUT Inserted.Id Into @T
   Select Name 
   From @Names

   Select * From @T
End
GO
```

Comment: You mean use Dynamic SQL?

Comment: I had no idea this was possible.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu. please test this solution in first.

Comment: There will be a lot of `TYPE` declarations this way, don't you think? I guess, one for each insert-update procedure?

Comment: @Prakhar Mishra. No. you only create one type IdList(Id int) and use this type for all of stored procedure that need to int list parameter.

Comment: Moreover, It will get worse when you are calling an `INSERT` Stored Procedure and want `IDENTITY` col back in calling function. Can we have TVPs as OUTPUT parameters?